# UserformTextbox input creates 2 new rows and inputs paste in each row

Tags: excel, vba

Following textboxs in userform:

```
ClientFirstName
ClientLastName
Referral1FirstName
Referral1LastName
```

Current Code:

```
Private Sub CommandBox_Click()
Dim emptyRow as Long 

'MakeSheet1 active
Sheet1.Activate

'Determine emptyRow
emptyRow = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A:A"))+1

'Transfer Information
Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = ClientFirstName.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = ClientLastName.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 3).Value = Referral1FirstName.Value
Cells(emptyRow, 4).Value = Referral1LastName.Value

End Sub
```

Ideally the textbox would input the data for empty Row 1 and then insert a new row where Columns C and D are in Row 2 (in positions Columns A and B)

Ideal Output

[image]

Comment: A tedious work around I found!

Answer (score 0):

To improve efficiency of your code a bit you could re-write it like below, but your logic looks sound and I'd expect the right outcomes? Below codee is assuming the `referralname` should be in the row below:

```
Private Sub CommandBox_Click()
Dim emptyRow as Long 
Dim TargetSheet as Worksheet

'Direct code to run on Sheet1
Set TargetSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheet1 'Could also be ThisWorkbook.Sheets("SheetNameHere")
With TargetSheet

    'Determine emptyRow                 
    emptyRow = TargetSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1

    'Transfer Information 
    .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Value = Me.ClientFirstName.Value 
    .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Value = Me.ClientLastName.Value
    'Assuiming you want the referral name values in the row below the client name, 
     'include 'Offset(1, 0) to offset the target by 1 row.
    .Cells(emptyRow, 1).Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.Referral1FirstName.Value
    .Cells(emptyRow, 2).Offset(1, 0).Value = Me.Referral1LastName.Value

End with

End Sub
```

Now we aren't relying on the `ActiveSheet` being the correct sheet at time of execution. 
Sometimes you can get some funky results with the way you were finding the last row, where the method i've used is the same as going to the end of the worksheet and holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>↑</kbd>.